# How to force Mathematica to throw an error for NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

Consider this:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

> 0.9999999999904574

This is the correct answer.

Now:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 40000}]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {78.125}. NIntegrate obtained -0.03826923022638286 and 0.03996030542184427` for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> Out[72]= -0.03826923022638286

The answer is not correct but it's fine because MMA throws an error.

Now this:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 50000}]
```

> 0.002477644409437118

Incorrect answer and no error.
How can I get an error in these situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To get the warning**

Raise the `PrecisionGoal`:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 50000}, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {97.6563}. NIntegrate obtained -0.00247946 and 0.004932015473174114` for the integral and error estimates. >>

```
(*  -0.00247946  *)
```

Or raise the number of `"Points"`:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 50000}, Method -> {"LevinRule", "Points" -> 11}]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {97.6563}. NIntegrate obtained 0.029764272686778833`and 0.029476870687760864` for the integral and error estimates. >>

```
(*  0.0297643  *)
```

**Some fixes**

Raise recursion:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 50000}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 20]

(*  1.00248  *)
```

Or raise the number of "Points" further:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 50000}, Method -> {"LevinRule", "Points" -> 101}]

(*  1.00248  *)
```

Or use infinite intervals:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, Infinity}] - 
 NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 50000, Infinity}]

(*  1.00248  *)
```

**How to detect**

Users are warned that the error estimator can be tricked in [`tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules#81420002`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#81420002). Some possible checks one might try are:  The default `PrecisionGoal` seems to be about `6`.  Raising this to `8` or `10` might lead to a significantly different result when the numerical integration has not yet converged.  I usually first try `WorkingPrecision -> 20`, which simultaneously raises `PrecisionGoal` to `10`.  In a highly oscillatory integral like this one (many periods over a finite interval), one has to worry about the sampling being sufficiently fine.  Note that infinite intervals are handled better in this case; I'm not sure what `NIntegrate` does differently, but integrals to infinity probably require a different sort of handling.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug. May be another branch cut bug. So, Mathematica can't throw an error, since it does not know that it is a bug.

```
sol = Integrate[BesselJ[2, x], x];
N[Limit[sol, x -> 50000] - Limit[sol, x -> 0]]
(* 1.00248   *)
```

The problem is in the `NIntegrate` when it evaluated the limits.

```
 sol = N[Integrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 50000}]]
 (*1.00248*)

 sol = NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 50000}]
 (*0.00247764*)
```

Version 10.02, windows.

Please report this to support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 1):

Just devide it into two integration ranges.

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 100, 50000}]

(*   1.00248   *)
```